# Long running shell command in ruby

Tags: ruby, shell, process, command

I want to launch and manage long running (several hours) shell commands on Linux, from a ruby script.
I need to be able to parse the output line by line, as they come. Not when the process is done.
I need to be able to kill the command and restart it if I don't like the output.
I also need to know if the process dies.

I found the right_popen gem but it hasn't been updated for 2 years and has no documentation. What would be the cleanest way to do all this?

Comment: Which OS?  When you say "shell commands" I assume we're talking about Linux / UNIX / BSD ?

Comment: Yes, Linux. I edited the question for others.

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution that allows me to do all the above, so I thought I'd share it with people who come after me :-)
We do it through pseudo-terminals, which are in stdlib (no gem required).

Here is an example of code that does what I need:

```
require 'pty'

cmd = 'for i in 1 2 3 4 5; do echo $i; sleep 1; done'
PTY.spawn cmd do |r, w, pid|
  begin
    r.sync
    r.each_line do |l|
      # Process each line immediately
      line = l.strip
      puts line
      if line == '3'
        # We kill the command on 3, because 3s are evil...
        ::Process.kill('SIGINT', pid)
      end
    end
  rescue Errno::EIO => e
    # Linux raises this error when the command ends
    puts "COMMAND DIED"
  ensure
    # Wait for the process to end before we go on
    ::Process.wait pid
    puts "WE ARE CLEAR"
  end
end
```

Output:

```
1
2
3
COMMAND DIED
WE ARE CLEAR
```